# How to configure jenkins such that build is triggered whenever a docker image is built?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a docker image whenever it is built, the Jenkins job should be executed, is there a configuration for that?

Comment: If you build the image inside Jenkins, you can call the 'build job' command whenever the image is built or setup a POST to the API to trigger the build.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin for Jenkins which allows for integration between Docker Hub and Jenkins via Web hooks - https://plugins.jenkins.io/dockerhub-notification/

You just add the plugin to your Jenkins server and then configure the web hook in your Docker Hub registry.

When new images are built it should notify the Jenkins server (so you can trigger the build) and also then you can use the image as part of your build job